# Eclipse kind of editor for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2008, editor, add-in

I have used Eclipse for years and when I started using VS 2008, it is good enough but misses lot of what Eclipse has or does so easily.

To mention a few, if I move my caret/cursor over an identifier, Eclipse highlights all of it's occurrences(not by string comparison but by reference mapping) in that document, we can differentiate between method & variable by colors, move to method above/below current function with `Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down` arrow combination.

VS misses all of these and more useful things. So just wondering if there is Eclipse kind of **free** editor add-in for VS 2008. Metal Scroll just does half of 1 thing (reference highlighting).

Are there any full feature add-ins?

Edit:
Didn't find any. Looks like VS 2010 is way to go, or may be VS 2012!

Comment: If you like Eclipse that much, maybe you could just use Eclipse? It has plugins for C, C++, etc. so I don't know if it would be possible to simply use it instead of Visual Studio altogether. Just throwing it out there, though I suspect the best you could do would be to just switch back and forth between the two frequently.

Comment: I feel your pain. I remember searching for plug-ins previously and came up pretty blank. I've tried CodeRush and trial of Resharper and found them to slow VS down considerably. One plug-in I did find handy was Quick Open File <http://kutny.net/vsopen/>. It allows you to use Ctrl-K+O to quickly open a file similar to how Open Type/Open File does in Eclipse. Maybe you could write a VS add-in to provide Eclipse like functionality. I'd give you a bounty of +50 reputation for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You may find [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/index.xml) and the [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/community.xml) ecosystem to be a very helpful addition to Visual Studio.

Comment: I have to add 1 add-in per feature and the available ones are not so good either. Appreciate your time Telarian anyway.

Comment: Well that's true for the community contributions but CodeRush and Refactor Pro include lots of features I find invaluable.

Comment: I am looking for something free and open source, cos community support comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Telerik  makes a product called JustCode that provides some good Eclipse-like features.  I especially like the blue/red/yellow rects that appear beside scrollbars to indicate where comments (blue), warnings (yellow) and errors (red) are.  It also places a red dot in the document's tab in Visual Studiu when it has edits and does all of the field highlighting you're talking about - also does the bracket matching highlighting you'd expect in a rich IDE.

http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx

Much of what it (just-code) does interactively has been covered in VS2010 but not all of it, and it's certainly substantailly cheaper than upgrading VS2008 to 2010.

Good luck - happy coding.

B

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you can get for free: [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef). It has `Ctrl+Click: Go to Definition` and many more.

To differentiate between variable and method by color, you have to customize it (`Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors`, but this is bit tedious).

I would suggest ReSharper for more advanced features but that's not free.

Comment: You cant do it there. VS treats both method and variable names as Identifier. So they cant have different colors.

Comment: hmmm... would have to look into this. language services provider knows the differennce, maybe thru an extension this could be possible.

Comment: Here's color enhancement extension (although the free beta seems to have expired, but might be cheaper than ReSharper) [VS10x Editor View Enhancer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87)